# How can squid be used in a Dockerfile to cache downloads in a host directory

Tags: docker, squid

I am running a `docker build` command with a Dockerfile, but this is being held up by a slow, and sometimes aborted, download of a certain package (google's boringssl as it happens).

I would like to install squid near the start of the Dockerfile, so that subsequent git clones, apt gets, etc, i.e. every kind of download is cached to a directory outside the docker image, by defining a volume in the `docker build` command.

I'm fairly familiar with Docker, and understand the concept of layers. So a reply dealing solely with those will not be useful to me (although possibly to others). But sometimes one has to make a Dockerfile change that disrupts subsequent layers, and also a build error of a subsystem within a layer will mean all the web fetches for that layer will need repeating on the next build. So layers are not the answer to everything cache-related.

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: A Docker image build can't run background processes, which limits this idea.  The ability to mount directories is somewhat limited as well, but [`RUN --mount=type=cache`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache) would give you (opaque) storage for this type of operation.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, in my case I could avoid the problem by copying the tink "build" directory out of the container, and on future devleopment builds simply copying it back in rather than re-building it from scratch. It's a shame the squid idea won't work inside a Docker build though. (Thanks for your prompt reply, David, BTW.)